# How to open dialog from fragment and implement listener pattern?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment that opens a dialogfragment. I use listener pattern. My original code used an activity directly and opening the dialog working fine.

In the dialogfragment I do:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    if (activity instanceof CustomListener) {
        listener = (CustomListener)activity;
    } else {
        throw new ClassCastException("Parent activity must implement CustomListener");
    }
}
```

But because now I'm moving from activity to fragment, the above doesn't work.

Should I pass the fragment as an argument?

Answer (score 0):

You can make an observer pattern in your custom `DialogFragment` then in the activity or fragment you will create it, you have to give it an instance of your Observer implementation:

```
public class CustomTwoFieldsDialog extends DialogFragment {

private TextView first_button_text_view, second_button_text_view;

public interface CustomTwoFieldsDialogListener {
    public void onBtnClick(int btnPos, Dialog dialog);

}

private CustomTwoFieldsDialogListener listener;

public void setListener(CustomTwoFieldsDialogListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

private void setButtonsClickingListeners() {
    first_button_text_view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listener.onBtnClick(0, getDialog());
        }
    });

    second_button_text_view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listener.onBtnClick(1, getDialog());
        }
    });
}}
```

Then come in your `Fragment` or your `Activity` that will use the custom `DialogFragment`

```
    CustomTwoFieldsDialog failureDialog = CustomTwoFieldsDialog
            .newInstance();

    failureDialog.setListener(new CustomTwoFieldsDialogListener {

        @Override
        public void onBtnClick(int btnPos, Dialog dialog) {
            // put the code you want to fire when click on the button
        }

    });

    failureDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), FAILURE_DIALOG_TAG);
```

Comment: This solution have a problem: if Activity and Fragments (and DialogFragment) are recreated due to a configuration change, the listener will be no more valid.